# Remove space from HTML tag with attribute

Tags: php, html, string, tags, space

Is there any way to write

```
<b style="color:red">asd</b>
```

without space after b ? 
like this

```
<bstyle="color:red">asd</b>
```

i want to use it as string without spaces and than i want to display it and it should work properly as html tags

i tried something like

```
<b&nbsp;style="color:red">asd</b>
```

but it didn´t work

This is part of string in which i want to find 100th space and than using php split the string. it makes issues if i split it in the midle of tag.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: this is part of longer text but i need to find space after 30. sign and there i need to cut the string ... and it shouldnt be in the midle of <b style="color:red">asd</b> because it will produce issues.

Comment: i think you dont need to remove the space. it's strange . ithink you need a php function. if you need the last occurrence of a space in a string use `strrpos("asdasdasd<b style='color:red'>asd</b> asdasd", " ",0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use css.

```
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
b { color:red; }
</style>
</head>

//Other code

<b>abc</b>
```

Other idea is in the php code. Have you tried to do this?:

```
<?php
 $string = 'asdfasdfa<b style="color:red">asd</b> asdfasdf';
 $string2 = str_replace('<b style', '<bstyle', $string);
 //And then do the search
 $search = strpos($string2, " ", 0);
?>
```

Comment: there is 10 other b tags with different colour ... so this is out

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have that work is if you use [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) on the string(s) after removing your spaces, like so:

```
$str = str_replace('bstyle', 'b style', $str);
```

where `$str` is a variable containing the text from which you've removed spaces.

Otherwise, the markup is invalid (and will likely be ignored by the browser).